# How can I make apt-get find a dependency I have built myself?

Tags: apt, dependencies, compiling

I am running Ubuntu 14.04. When I run

```
sudo apt-get install gazebo2
```

`apt-get` complains it cannot find `libsdformat(<=2.0)`

`apt-get` doesn't provide `libsdformat(<=2.0)`, so I have built libsdformat1.4 from the source.

How can I make `apt-get` find a dependency I have built myself?

Comment: `gazebo2` is not provided in the official repositories, either. Where are you getting it from?

Answer (score 0):

First, convert your files into a .deb file.

To do that, install dpkg-dev if it's not installed.
Next, put all your files into one folder and use dpkg-dev to create a file that can be read by apt.

Now, upload that file to a website where you want people to download it from.

Now add that URL in the sources list.

Now, the file should be downloadable using apt commands.